# Orthogonal Projection of a convex hypersurface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, convex-geometry

Suppose I have an $n-1$ dimensional convex hypersurface $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I know $o\notin\Omega$ and $\Omega$ is contained in some closed half space.

Is it true that I can always choose a direction $v$ such that

1. $\Omega \subset \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: x\cdot v\leq 0\}$ and
2. $o$ is in the the interior of the image of the orthogonal projection of $\Omega$ onto $v^\perp$?

Comment: By closed half-space you mean an affine half-space or a linear half-space? If the latter, that's the definition of 1.

Comment: @TedShifrin Linear. Yes, it is exactly the definition of 1. But I need 1 and 2 to hold at the same time.

Comment: Can you plz rewrite the second question , via math notations?